# Wechaty Error: WatchdogAgent reset: lastFood

Tags: wechaty

This error is that when I am using the WeChat robot WeChat package and there is no message for a period of time, sending a message again will trigger

```
WARN PuppetWatchdogAgent start() reset() reason: {"data":"heartbeat@browserbridge ding","timeoutMilliseconds":60000}
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

GError: WatchdogAgent reset: lastFood: "{"data":"heartbeat@browserbridge ding","timeoutMilliseconds":60000}"
    at Watchdog.reset (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty-puppet/dist/esm/src/agents/watchdog-agent.js:45:39)
    at Watchdog.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Watchdog.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/watchdog/dist/esm/src/watchdog.js:81:18)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
Emitted 'error' event on WechatyImpl instance at:
    at WechatyImpl.emit (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty/dist/esm/src/wechaty-mixins/gerror-mixin.js:45:26)
    at PuppetWeChat.<anonymous> (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty/dist/esm/src/wechaty-mixins/puppet-mixin.js:155:34)
    at PuppetWeChat.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at PuppetWeChat.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at PuppetWeChat.emit (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty-puppet/dist/esm/src/puppet/puppet-skeleton.js:107:22)
    at Watchdog.reset (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty-puppet/dist/esm/src/agents/watchdog-agent.js:45:25)
    at Watchdog.emit (node:events:513:28)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17) {
  code: 2,
  details: 'Error: WatchdogAgent reset: lastFood: "{"data":"heartbeat@browserbridge ding","timeoutMilliseconds":60000}"\n' +
    '    at Watchdog.reset (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty-puppet/dist/esm/src/agents/watchdog-agent.js:45:39)\n' +
    '    at Watchdog.emit (node:events:513:28)\n' +
    '    at Watchdog.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at Timeout._onTimeout (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/watchdog/dist/esm/src/watchdog.js:81:18)\n' +
    '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)\n' +
    '    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)'
}
```

I don't now how to fixed it?
Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WatchdogAgent reset: lastFood: "{"data":"heartbeat@browserbridge ding","timeoutMilliseconds":60000}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76023053/watchdogagent-reset-lastfood-dataheartbeatbrowserbridge-ding-timeoutm)

Comment: Next time, *edit* your question instead of posting a revised version.  Also, this version is not about the Puppet configuration management system, either.