# WatchdogAgent reset: lastFood: "{"data":"heartbeat@browserbridge ding","timeoutMilliseconds":60000}"

Tags: javascript, wechaty

I am making a wechat rebot base on wechaty package.
However, if nothing is done for a while, it will happen.
How to fixed it?

```
WARN PuppetWatchdogAgent start() reset() reason: {"data":"heartbeat@browserbridge ding","timeoutMilliseconds":60000}
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

GError: WatchdogAgent reset: lastFood: "{"data":"heartbeat@browserbridge ding","timeoutMilliseconds":60000}"
    at Watchdog.reset (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty-puppet/dist/esm/src/agents/watchdog-agent.js:45:39)
    at Watchdog.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Watchdog.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/watchdog/dist/esm/src/watchdog.js:81:18)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
Emitted 'error' event on WechatyImpl instance at:
    at WechatyImpl.emit (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty/dist/esm/src/wechaty-mixins/gerror-mixin.js:45:26)
    at PuppetWeChat.<anonymous> (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty/dist/esm/src/wechaty-mixins/puppet-mixin.js:155:34)
    at PuppetWeChat.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at PuppetWeChat.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at PuppetWeChat.emit (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty-puppet/dist/esm/src/puppet/puppet-skeleton.js:107:22)
    at Watchdog.reset (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty-puppet/dist/esm/src/agents/watchdog-agent.js:45:25)
    at Watchdog.emit (node:events:513:28)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17) {
  code: 2,
  details: 'Error: WatchdogAgent reset: lastFood: "{"data":"heartbeat@browserbridge ding","timeoutMilliseconds":60000}"\n' +
    '    at Watchdog.reset (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/wechaty-puppet/dist/esm/src/agents/watchdog-agent.js:45:39)\n' +
    '    at Watchdog.emit (node:events:513:28)\n' +
    '    at Watchdog.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at Timeout._onTimeout (file:///opt/web/wechat-gpt/node_modules/watchdog/dist/esm/src/watchdog.js:81:18)\n' +
    '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)\n' +
    '    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)'
}
```

I hope to fix it?
Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know what PuppetWatchdogAgent is, but it definitely is not part of the Puppet configuration management system, to which the [puppet] tag pertains.  Tag removed.